# How to cut the output of my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am a python beginner and I am actually writing  a programm which calculates the area of an circle by asking the user for an radius.
My Problem: The ouput is like this '47529.15525615998'
So my question is how to shorten the output so that it would be for example '47529.155'?

- Here is my code:

  import math

  def compute_area(r):

  area=(r*r)*math.pi

  print(float(area),("Centimeter"))

  r=(float(input("Radius: ")))

  compute_area(r)

Answer (score 0):

use the following format to truncate float ("%.Nf") N=number of points after .

print("%.3f" %float(area),("Centimeter"))